# Not able to store data using react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have created Login.js component and there are 2 actions one is loginAction.js and second logoutAction.js and a userReducer.js I am getting accessToken as undefined in console. How can I store accessToken in asyncstorage on clicking login button. Note: I am using redux thunk middleware.

I have implemented Login functionality without using redux and asyncstorage i.e using internal state variable see original code below: (But I want to implement it now with redux and asyncstorage)

Original code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { accessToken: null };
  }

  _onLogin = () => {
    auth0.webAuth
      .authorize({
        scope: 'openid profile',
        audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'
      })
      .then(credentials => {
        Alert.alert(
          'Success',
          'AccessToken: ' + credentials.accessToken,
          [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') }],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
        this.setState({ accessToken: credentials.accessToken });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```

Login.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { loginUser } from '../actions/loginAction';
    import { logoutUser } from '../actions/logoutAction';

    class Login extends Component {

      render() {

        console.log(this.props)

        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
            onPress={loginUser}
            title="Click to Login"
            ></Button>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  accessToken: state.accessToken
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(Login);
```

loginAction.js:

```
import { LOGIN_USER } from './types';
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

var credentials = require('./auth0-credentials');
const auth0 = new Auth0(credentials);

export const loginUser = () => dispatch => {
    auth0.webAuth
    .authorize({
      scope: 'openid profile',
      audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'
    })
    .then(credentials =>

        _storeData = async () => {
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', credentials.accessToken);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        },

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_USER,
            payload: credentials.accessToken
        })
    )
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

userReducer.js:

```
import { LOGIN_USER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    accessToken: null
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case LOGIN_USER:

            return {
               ...state,
               accessToken:action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Converted original code into actions and reducer but accessToken is undefined.

Comment: You never call the `_storeData` function.

Comment: @Titus Should I move it inside `dispatch()` ? How can I store accessToken in asyncstorage ?

Comment: Just call the function (eg: `_storeData()`)

Comment: @Titus My original code works perfect i.e without redux but when I try to use redux it is difficult for me as I am new to redux. In original code i.e internal state variable when I click on login button it redirects user to web browser auth0 authentication but with redux nothing is happening

Comment: @Titus check this how original code works -> https://imgur.com/a/BWBTgQw

Comment: That is because in your original code you change the state when you get the token. In the new one, you don't.

Comment: @Titus I tried implementing it but in new one what am I missing ?

Comment: That is not evident from the code you've posted. The difference seems to be that in the old one you're changing the state `this.setState({ accessToken: credentials.accessToken });` which will cause a re-render, in the new one, you're changing the `props`, you're setting `this.props.accessToken`. There is also the `Alert.alert....` in the old one.

Comment: @Titus Can you please write an answer I am still confused how to connect all actions and reducers  with Login.js. Alert is just to show accesstoken but In redux implementation I am not able to get accesstoken ? I am getting undefined in console

Comment: @Titus Onclick loginUser action must be fired which stores accessToken in asyncstorage and when the token is received user is navigated to web browser where he enters email/password on auth0 website. Can you please tell me how can I proceed and I am unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not evident what you're trying to do (at least to me) from the code that you've posted but I will try to suggest a solution.

First, you never call the `_storeData` function which means that the token is not stored.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../actions/loginAction';
import { logoutUser } from '../actions/logoutAction';

    class Login extends Component {

      // Monitor props changes
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
          // Token was changed
          if(prevProps.accessToken !== this.props.accessToken){
             if(this.props.accessToken){
                 Alert.alert(
                   'Success',
                   'AccessToken: ' + credentials.accessToken,
                   [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') 
                   }],
                   { cancelable: false }
                 );
                 this.setState({ accessToken: credentials.accessToken });
             }
          }
      }

      render() {

        console.log(this.props)

        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
            onPress={loginUser}
            title="Click to Login"
            ></Button>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  accessToken: state.accessToken
})

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { loginUser, logoutUser })(Login);
```

loginAction.js:

```
import { LOGIN_USER } from './types';
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

var credentials = require('./auth0-credentials');
const auth0 = new Auth0(credentials);

export const loginUser = () => dispatch => {
    auth0.webAuth
    .authorize({
      scope: 'openid profile',
      audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'
    })
    .then(credentials =>

        _storeData = async () => {
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', credentials.accessToken);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        };
        // Call the function to store the token
        _storeData();

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_USER,
            payload: credentials.accessToken
        })
    )
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: I am trying to implement login feature using auth0 see this screnshot : https://imgur.com/a/BWBTgQw the screenshot is of original code which is working.

Comment: @funjoker Take a look at the changes that I've made, I've also added comments to them to explain what they do.

Comment: I want to implement login screen using redux and not using internally state so why are you doing `this.setState({ accessToken: credentials.accessToken })` in Login.js ? Original code is react native sample code on github -> https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-react-native-sample/blob/master/00-Login/app/index.js

Comment: @funjoker I'm doing that because that is what the old code does when the token is set.
It is not evident what should happen when the token is set.
Redux and internal state are not mutually exclusive

Comment: But above code is not working i.e when I click on login button it doesn't navigate to web browser ? I want to ask you in mapStateToProps is this correct -> `accessToken: state.accessToken`

Comment: Also this line-> `await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', action.payload);` must be -> `await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', credentials.accessToken);` am I right ?

Comment: @funjoker Yes, that is correct, that will set `this.props.accessToken` after the `dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_USER`....` call. It will also call the `componentDidUpdate` function I've added.

Comment: @funjoker Yes. I've missed that, it is `credentials.accessToken`

Comment: It still doesn't work why ? The original code works fine see this -> https://imgur.com/a/BWBTgQw after the user is navigated to web browser and then entering details gives back accessToken but new redux code doesn't navigate to web browser.

Comment: In loginUser should everything must be inside return() ?